Unable to attach a file in Gmail using Selenium automation using Java
This is my code, where After clicking on attachment symbol it's not taking the path and eclipse is not showing any error. Please help me how to resolve this.
// compose button //div[@class='T-I T-I-KE L3'] //div[@class='z0'] driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='z0']")).click();

    // to maximize the compose window //img[@id=":mo"]
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id=\":mo\"]")).click();
    
    // To address   //input[@id=":ta"]
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\":ta\"]")).sendKeys("jyotsnapandith97@gmail.com");
    // Subject  //input[@name='subjectbox']
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("Automation test");
    // Body to write    //div[@id=':qy']
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':qy']")).sendKeys("Hi, This is an Automated Script.. Thank you");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    

    String path = "D:\\Selenium\\SeleniumLogo.png";
    WebElement attachment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\":rc\"]"));
    attachment.sendKeys(path);
    attachment.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    
    // send button  //div[@id=":pe"]
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\":pe\"]")).click();[where After clicking on attachment symbol it's not taking the path and eclipse is not showing any error](https://i.sstatic.net/V0bLNMzt.png)

I have tried to send an attachment using xpath where, it found out the webelement of attachment symbol but didn't take the path.
And in the eclipse it's not even showing the error as attached in the screenshot.
Please help me how to resolve this. I am a fresher.

Can you share the exception stacktrace that you're getting on execution of the code?

when sending a file path to an <input type="file"... element, you won't want to click it afterwards.  (That'll open a file browse...)  You can instead use submit() convenience method.  ex: attachment.submit()  this will submit the form.

Techrookie89
Hi, it is not showing any error or exception, it inspected the attachment web element then it opened file window but not taking any path and then sent the mail without any error or exception at the console.

@browsermator
Hi, thank you for the suggestion but it showing an error as pasted below. I am not aware of this method, please tell me how write the code for this issue...      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: To submit an element, it must be nested inside a form element

either the locator (//*[@id=":rc"]) is wrong, or it's somehow outside of the .  Include the page's markup in your post.  (right-click on the page and choose "inspect", copy/paste relevant markup)
